# Why Resharper does not recognize referenced project in Unit Test

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm facing this issue with Resharper in a Unit Test Project class.

It does not recognize my referenced main project (and also all its objects) arguing:

> Cannot resolve symbol "[Project Namespace]"
>   Using directive is not required by the code and it can be safetly removed

[image: Resharper problem]

I could disable this feature in options by it works nice in a common project, this problem only happens in my Unit Test Project, as far as I could see.

Comment: Try clearing the cache. You can find the location of the cache on the options page, under Environment -> General. If it's in the solutions folder, you should reopen the solution afterwards.

Comment: Worked! Thanks! It's not in solution folder, but even so I needed to restart the solution.

Comment: Reposted it as a real answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is usually a sign of the ReSharper cache going stale or out of touch with the solution. I've experienced it a lot with the 7.x version of ReSharper, and I've yet to experience it with 8.x so it might be a bug they've fixed.

Anyway, to fix it, go to the ReSharper options, under Environment and General, and find the cache settings near the bottom:

[image: ReSharper cache settings]

Click the Clear Caches button and then reload your solution. Problem should be fixed now.

Comment: I opted to keep mine set to User local, but this pointed me in the right direction with clearing cache and relaunching VS after switching to a fundamentally different branch in Git.